# Do not use DB but Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL 12) Storage increase ~17M/5Min

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I do not use DB but Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL 12) Storage increase ~17M/5Min

I have 3 instances and the same setting but 2 instances the storage increase ~17M/5Min

How to solve it?

[See Monitoring Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/relBk.png)

Comment: Could you compare the increase with the number of Write operation you have during the same time period?

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable "Enable point-in-time recovery" feature - it was the reason in my case.